# Graph visit every node once and reach exit

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, depth-first-search

I had a test right now and this was one of the questions:

**Input**

The places to visit in the labyrinth are numbered from 1 to n. The entry and
the exit correspond to number 1 and number n, respectively; the remaining
numbers correspond to crossings. Note that there are no dead ends and
there is no more than one connection linking a pair of crossings.
For each test case, the first line gives n and the number of connections
between crossings (m). Then, in each of the following m lines, you find a pair
of integers corresponding to the connection between two crossings.

**Output**

For each test case, your implementation should output one single line
containing "Found!", if it is possible to reach the exit by visiting every
crossing once or "Damn!", otherwise. Other test cases may follow.

**Constraints**

- m < 32
- n < 21

**Example input:**

```
8 13
1 2
1 3
2 3    
2 4    
3 4    
3 5    
4 5    
4 6    
5 6    
5 7
6 7
6 8    
7 8    
8 8    
1 2    
1 3    
2 4    
3 5    
4 6    
5 7    
6 8    
7 8
```

**Example output:**

```
Found!
Damn!
```

---

I solved the problem using a sort of DFS algorithm but i have a few questions.

Using DFS algorithm, I implemented a recursive function that starts in the given node and tries to visit every node once and the last node must be the exit node. I don't have the full code right now but but it was something like this:

```
findPath(int current node, int numVisitedNodes, int *visited){
    int *tmpVisited = copyArray(visited); //copies the visited array to tmpVisited

    //DFS algo here
}
```

Every recursive call it copies the visited nodes array. I'm doing this because when it finds an invalid path and the recursion goes back to the origin, it can still go because no one overwrote the visited nodes list.

**Is there any better way to do this?**

**How would you solve it? (you can provide code if you want)**

Comment: The problem statement seems inconsistent - it says "visiting every crossing not more than once" (implying 0 times or once), then it says "by visiting every crossing once" (implying exactly once). Also - you really should post the problem statement as text rather than an image (yes, I realize you'll probably need to rewrite it - preferably remove the back story as well).

Comment: Wow, I want to write these kinds of tests as well.

Comment: @Dukeling, done. OCR is the best :D you should visit every node exactly 1 time

Comment: Visiting every node exactly once sounds a lot like the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: @Dukeling: Since there is no requirement to find a shortest path, it's actually the less general Hamiltonian path problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the crossing
2. if start or end of the crossing belongs to a reachable set, add both to that set else create a new reachable set.
3. When input has finished, check if any of the reachable sets contains
   both entrance and exit points

HashSet operations complexity is O(1). If every crossing are distinct, complexity is O(n^2),which is the worst case complexity of this algorithm. Space complexity is O(n), there is no recursion so there is no recursion overhead of memory.

Roughly speaking, every node is visited only once.

Java code using valid reachable sets is as follows.

```
public class ZeManel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] input = {{1,2},{2,3},{4,6}};
        zeManel(input);
    }

    public static void zeManel(Integer[][] input){
        List<Set<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < input.length;i++) {
            max = input[i][0] > max ? input[i][0] : max;
            max = input[i][1] > max ? input[i][1] : max; 
            boolean inPaths = false;
            for (Set<Integer> set : paths) {    
                if(set.contains(input[i][0]) || set.contains(input[i][1])) {
                    set.add(input[i][0]);
                    set.add(input[i][1]);
                    inPaths = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!inPaths) {
                Set<Integer> path = new HashSet<Integer>();
                path.add(input[i][0]);
                path.add(input[i][1]);
                paths.add(path);
            }

        }
        for (Set<Integer> path : paths) {
            if(path.contains(1) && path.contains(max)) {
                System.out.println("Found!");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Damn!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Either your program is incorrect, your analysis of your program is incorrect, or you have just shown that P = NP.

Comment: Your assumption based on your perception about the question. If you clearly identify which well-known NP Problem you resemble this problem, I will help more.

Comment: Hamiltonian path, as I mentioned in the comments

Comment: **if it is possible to reach the exit by visiting every crossing once**,  yes you are right with this definition. When I read the previous version of the question with images, I thought that any path reaching the exit starting from first node regardless of visiting each vertex. As you said that's Hamiltonian path. But in previous version definition was **visiting every crossing not more than once**.

Answer (score 0):

**This was my implementation during the test:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

# define N 21
# define M 32

int i;
int adj[N][N];
int count = 0;

int findPath(int numNodes, int currentNode, int depth, int *visited){

    visited[currentNode] = 1;

    if(currentNode == numNodes - 1 && depth == numNodes){
        return 1;
    }

    if(depth > numNodes)
        return -1;

    int r = -1;

    if(depth < numNodes){
        count++;
        int *tmp = (int*) malloc(numNodes*sizeof(int));
        for(i = 0; i < numNodes; i++)
            tmp[i] = visited[i];


        for(i = 0; i < numNodes; i++){

            if(adj[currentNode][i] == 1 && tmp[i] == 0 && r == -1){
                if(findPath(numNodes, i, depth + 1, tmp) == 1)
                    r = 1;
            }

        }

        free(tmp);
    }
    return r;
}

int main(){

    int numLigacoes, a, b, numNodes;
    int *visited;

    while (scanf("%d %d", &numNodes, &numLigacoes) != EOF){
        visited = (int*) malloc(numNodes*sizeof(int));
        count = 0;
        memset(adj, 0, N*N*sizeof(int));
        memset(visited, 0, numNodes*sizeof(int));

        for (i = 0; i < numLigacoes; i++){
            scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
            adj[a - 1][b - 1] = 1;
            adj[b - 1][a - 1] = 1;
        }

        if(findPath(numNodes, 0, 1, visited) == 1)
            printf("Found! (%d)\n", count);
        else
            printf("Damn! (%d)\n", count);

        free(visited);
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

**What do you think about that?**

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n!) so you won't be happy using this when n = 20. There is a simple O(n^2 * 2^n) dynamic programming approach